# Android: How to print an HTML page directly on Samsung Mobile Print

Tags: android, android-intent, printing, samsung-mobile

I'm developing an Android application and I want to print an HTML page via the Samsung Mobile Print app. What are the intent parameters that I need to do this i.e.

- package name
- MIME type
- Action type (`ACTION_SEND`, `ACTION_VIEW` e.t.c)
- any other parameters that are required.

Is there a way I can find out these parameters? I managed to find out the package name using adb shell but when I tried to pass the HTML page as a bundle, it throw an `ActivityNotFoundException (No Activity found to handle ACTION_SEND)`.

I know there are other options for printing such as PrinterShare Pro and Gooble Cloud Print but I'm developing this application for a client and so I have to communicate with the Samsung Mobile Print app.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I contacted the developers of the Samsung Mobile Print app and they provided the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.sec.print.mobileprint.action.PRINT");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.samsung.com");
intent.putExtra("com.sec.print.mobileprint.extra.CONTENT", uri );
intent.putExtra("com.sec.print.mobileprint.extra.CONTENT_TYPE", "WEBPAGE");
intent.putExtra("com.sec.print.mobileprint.extra.OPTION_TYPE", "DOCUMENT_PRINT");
intent.putExtra("com.sec.print.mobileprint.extra.JOB_NAME", "Untitled");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Can you please provide the link where you have found above details?

Comment: If you're printing local HTML file, make sure to write your URI as "file:///pathtoyourfile/yourfile.html", otherwise Samsung Mobile Print will open your path as Google query.

Comment: Found [Calling Samsung Mobile Print Via Intent](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/file.do?attachmentId=17452)