# How to print an HTML content directly on Samsung Mobile Print

Tags: android, android-intent, printing

The question is relate to "How to print an HTML page directly on Samsung Mobile Print" at
[Android: How to print an HTML page directly on Samsung Mobile Print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474837/android-how-to-print-an-html-page-directly-on-samsung-mobile-print/20400932#20400932), and when post in that thread it is deleted, so put it here. Thanks!

The different part is if the content I want to print is not a web page but some content of internal programmatically generated html data and has image url points to internal resource, is it possible for Samsung Print app to print the content with the image (the problem with Google Cloud Print is the image url cannot be accessed by GCP)?

The Intent tried is like following to see if it can print a local html file (get error of 'type not supported):

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.sec.print.mobileprint.action.PRINT");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
intent.putExtra("com.sec.print.mobileprint.extra.CONTENT", uri );
intent.putExtra("com.sec.print.mobileprint.extra.CONTENT_TYPE", "DOCUMENT");
//Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.samsung.com");
//intent.putExtra("com.sec.print.mobileprint.extra.CONTENT_TYPE", "WEBPAGE");
intent.putExtra("com.sec.print.mobileprint.extra.OPTION_TYPE", "DOCUMENT_PRINT");
intent.putExtra("com.sec.print.mobileprint.extra.JOB_NAME", "Untitled");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: check this tutorial http://www.androidpit.de/forum/579394/html-zu-jpeg-konvertieren

Answer (score 2):

You should modify the code form your question according to your needs, using the official manual/API, provided [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.samsung.com%2Fforum%2Fboard%2Fthread%2Ffile.do%3FattachmentId%3D17452&ei=q1LdU7zALOn14QTh4oCYDg&usg=AFQjCNG9OhMwFBCAKEG7hDHpxje5-h4g0A&sig2=gagE3jqo7OQ-Vy2jrO9eww).

What the manual (linked above) example says about the printing of documents:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.sec.print.mobileprint.action.PRINT");   
String rootSDCard= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
Uri uri= Uri.parse(rootSDCard+ "/Test_document.pdf");
intent.putExtra("com.sec.print.mobileprint.extra.CONTENT", uri );
intent.putExtra("com.sec.print.mobileprint.extra.CONTENT_TYPE", "DOCUMENT");
intent.putExtra("com.sec.print.mobileprint.extra.OPTION_TYPE", "DOCUMENT_PRINT");
intent.putExtra("com.sec.print.mobileprint.extra.JOB_NAME", "Untitled");
startActivity(intent); // Starts Mobile Print
//startActivityForResult(intent , 99) // Use this if you want to get result that user
//pressed Print or just returned back from Mobile Print.
```

For CONTENT_TYPE flag it states the following: [image]