# Open printer applications in popup in xamarin android

Tags: mono, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I want to send print request through my Xamarin.Android app to a printer using any of the installed printer apps on my device.
When I click Print button ,a popup will be shown to user which displays all the available printer apps on a device.
User can choose an appropriate app and send print request.
The selected app will handle the print request such as searching for available printers and send request to a available printer.

Answer (score 0):

As of Android 4.4 there still isn't a Print Intent available in Android.

The closest available option is:
http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/11/android-gets-a-print-framework/

There are examples of 3rd party apps that can print as well.
But those do not expose a general Print Intent.

[Android Print intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917008/android-print-intent)

Comment: sir ,that webpage contains how to open google cloud print in xamarin.Android.How my app should detect all the print apps installed on my device ? Please guide me,I am new to all these.

Comment: Ah, right, should've read more carefully.

Thought it contained an example of a Print Intent, but apparently such an intent still doesn't exist. (Updated my answer to reflect that).

Comment: sir,what if I want to print using device having Android version older than kitkat(4.4)?